# How to display image from dynamic path in node ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to display image based on the path I get from database

here's my code

```
<% cars.forEach(function(car) { %>

          <div class="card">
               <div class="img">
                    <img src="images/" +"<%=car.Img_path %>">
               </div>
          </div>

<% }); %>
```

I also tried `<img src="images/<%=car.Img_path %>">` but not working.

Can Anyone suggest how to render image.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="images/<%=car.Img_path %>">` works. My issue was i didn't included `Img_path` in car model.

whoever may get this type of issue make sure you have included that field in model otherwise you will have data in database for but you wont get it in your application